# Client asking for WAR file

Tags: war

I am doing some freelance work in my spare time, and I have just completed a messaging application using PHP and Javascript. I have the source code ready to send to the client, however they are requesting to "have the files as a **WAR** file".

How would I put together a **WAR** file?

Comment: Consider looking at this link http://www.javatpoint.com/war-file

Comment: My understanding is that WAR files are related to Java web based projects. I've been asked the same, place project into a war file, for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

A WAR file (web application archive) is an archive that contains the binaries of an application, but is specific to Java based web applications.